# Mass sending data to stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml, vb.net, stored-procedures

I'm using Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 to create a web service with VB.NET. I'm using a Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2008 so that SQL can insert all the data that I'm passing.

The problem is that in one of the servicse I need to pass around 10,000 records and it's not very efficient to run the stored procedure 10,000 times.

I read that there is a way in which you can pass an XML file with all data to the Stored Procedure but I'm not sure if that's the most efficient way. Also I couldn't make the code work, I don't know if I have to pass the XML as a String.

I'm asking for help with a method in which I can pass a lots of records to the stored procedure once and then the same instance of the Stored procedure can process all the records in a loop

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [SqlBulkCopy in .NET](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/use-sqlbulkcopy-to-quickly-load-data-from-your-client-to-sql-server), but I expect you'll want to look at a [table-valued parameter.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx)

Comment: I'm going to go with SqlBulkCopy as well. I use on a regular basis for anything that has 1,000 to 10 million rows.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a **text *batch* of statements** to the database.  It can be quite efficient.

Instead of creating a `SqlCommand` of `CommandType.StoredProcedure` and taking a single stored procedure name and set of parameters – which, as you suspect, will perform poorly if you round-trip to the database for each record – you can instead create a `SqlCommand` of `CommandType.Text`, and then construct a text batch containing multiple SQL statements (which would be invocations of your stored procedure.)  Separate each statement with a semi-colon.

Another advantage of a text batch is that your stored procedure can be kept simple and just process a single record at a time.

But, **be careful:** You need to ensure your parameters are properly quoted / escaped, because creating a plain text batch instead of using `CommandType.StoredProcedure` (with parameters) opens you up to SQL-injection type vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

The method I use is to pass the data in a CDATA block (pipe delimited in my case) to the web service, which then:

1. Saves the CDATA block to a temp file on the web server
2. Then uses the command line utility bcp.exe to bulk load the data into a staging table
3. Then calls the stored procedure which is set up to process all the records in the staging table

much faster and less strain on the database than calling the proc for each record.

Edit: Now that I've read about SqlBulkCopy, I would do this instead:

1. Write the CDATA block data into a DataTable
2. Use SqlBulkCopy to put the data into a staging table :-)
3. Then calls the stored procedure which is set up to process all the records in the staging table

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx

This may also help: http://sqlxml.org/faqs.aspx?faq=61

Answer (score 0):

Where I've done this before with SQL Server 2000, I've used `OPENXML` (as @EJB suggested) by constructing an XML string in my code, passing it into a stored proc in a `text` parameter, using `OPENXML` to parse the XML into a relational structure and going on from there e.g.

VB

```
Dim xmlStringBuilder As System.Text.StringBuilder

xmlStringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder
xmlStringBuilder.Append("<objects>"
For Each object In Collection
    'I'm not suggesting this is the best way to build XML, it is however reliable!
    xmlStringBuilder.Append("<object id='" & object.id.ToString & "'></object>"
Next
xmlStringBuilder.Append("</objects>"

Dim xmlStoredProcCommand As SqlCommand
Dim xmlParameter As SqlParameter
xmlStoredProcCommand = New SqlCommand(connection)
xmlStoredProcCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
xmlStoredProcCommand.CommandText = "xmlStoredProc"
xmlParameter = New SqlParameter("@xmlParameter",SqlDbType.NText)
xmlParameter.Value = xmlStringBuilder.ToString
xmlStoredProcCommand.Parameters.Add(xmlParameter)
xmlStoredProcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery
```

SQL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE xmlStoredProc
@xmlParameter NTEXT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @xmldochandle INT
    DECLARE @objects TABLE (objectID INT)

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @xmldochandle OUTPUT, @xmlParameter

    INSERT INTO @objects (objectId)
    SELECT objectId
    FROM OPENXML(@xmldochandle, 'objects/object')
    WITH (objectId INT)

    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @xmldochandle
END
```

and from there you can do your stuff with the contents of the @objects table variable.